# Android: HowTo make device theme

Tags: android, themes

perhaps I don't know how to search for that - everything I found only is about changing the app theme.
I want to know how I can develop a whole theme for the android device itself?
On the market you'll find many themes out there - how can I build one, too?

I don't want to use 3rd party licences (ThemeMaker etc)...anyone who has a tutorial for me?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on the Android Developer site - **Styles and Themes** http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

A style is a collection of properties that specify the look and format for a View or window. A style can specify properties such as height, padding, font color, font size, background color, and much more. A style is defined in an XML resource that is separate from the XML that specifies the layout.

Styles in Android share a similar philosophy to cascading stylesheets in web design—they allow you to separate the design from the content.

**Apply a theme to an Activity or application**

To set a theme for all the activities of your application, open the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and edit the `<application>` tag to include the android:theme attribute with the style name. For example:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

If you like a theme, but want to tweak it, just add the theme as the parent of your custom theme. For example, you can modify the traditional light theme to use your own color like this:

```
<color name="custom_theme_color">#b0b0ff</color>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I know that already - because of this I wrote that I want to change the theme of the whole device, not of my application/view!